# React component tabs and URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-tabs

I'm fairly new to React so please bare with me.

We have a list of  elements which all load their own content based on a query string parameter (let's call it ***CustomerID***) passed in to the page. When clicking on the tabs, the URL remains the same. Let's say the URL is /customer/*customerid*

Within one of the tabs, the user has an opportunity to click on other items relevant to this Customer, which in turn changes the URL and another id is passed into the query string, let's call it ***OrderID*** and the URL is /customer/order/*orderid*.

When viewing the order, I would like the customer Tab menu to still appear, but I'm not sure the best way to handle this. Should I abandon tabs, and just create some normal links that look and feel like tabs? Or should I make the menu a class that is imported into each page, passing in the ***CustomerID*** from the relevant payloads each page contains?

**EDIT:** to include some code as a reference:

```
  <Formik
    initialValues={customer}
    enableReinitialize={true}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
    {({ isSubmitting, values }) => (
      <FormikForm autoComplete="off">
        <AppCard>
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey="details">
            <Tab eventKey="details" title="Details">
              <Row>
                <Col md>
                  <InputText name="firstName" label="First Name" />
                </Col>
                <Col md>
                  <InputText name="lastName" label="Last Name" />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="orders" title="Orders">
              <CustomerOrders
                onCustomerOrderClick={onCustomerOrderClick}
                customerId={customer.customerId}/>
            </Tab>

          </Tabs>
        </AppCard>
      </FormikForm>
    )}
  </Formik>

  function onCustomerOrderClick(orderId: any){
    history.push(`/customer/order/edit/${orderId}`);
  }
```

The CustomerOrders class contains links to each individual order... Something like the following:

```
   <Row>
      <Col className="DataRowFunctions" md="2">
      <Link
        to={onCustomerOrderClick}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          onCustomerOrderClick();
        }}
      >
       Edit   
      </Link>
      </Col>
</Row>
```

Opening the order is then changing the URL, which leads me back to my question.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: @CornelRaiu I just edited to include some code snippets, not sure if it is overly useful though in terms of my question asked.

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom? Life would be a lot better if you do

Comment: @Normal we do... Why?

Comment: Since these layouts have intersections together, and since the key between the two layouts is the URL, why you don't make the outer Tabs layout in a `<Route element={<TabsLayout children={<Outlet />} />}` and the second one inside? you can play with that well if you're using react-router-dom

Comment: @Normal interesting, do you think you could send me a link to a bigger example as I'm not familiar with this?